# Use a different Nlog renderer for the same target?

Tags: c#, nlog

I have taken over a project that uses a very simple NLog configuration ... the only target is a text file, there is only one rule, and the layout is the default text layout.

It has been fine until today when I had a need to send blocks of raw lines (i.e., unrendered by any NLog layout, or rendered by a different layout for the same target)

These blocks of unformatted lines will be sent to the same target as normally rendered lines.

Before, I was writing to the target with *only* the default simple text layout. For example ...

```
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| This line rendered by simple text layout
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| And so was this
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| But...
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| 
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| I wish this sequence of lines was 
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| rendered by a different layout which
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| only printed the message itself.
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| (i.e., suppress datetime, level and source)
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| 
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| And...
    2020-05-01 13:57:58.3275|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| Then I could return to the original 
    2020-05-01 13:57:58.3275|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| layout for subsequent lines! 
    2020-05-01 13:57:58.3275|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| So I could send more
    2020-05-01 13:57:58.3275|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| useless information to the target (LOL)
```

But I *want* to write to the same target using different layouts. For example...

```
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| This line rendered by simple text layout
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| And so was this
    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| But...

    I wish this sequence of lines was 
    rendered by a different layout which
    only printed the message itself.
    (i.e., suppress the datetime, level and source)

    2020-05-01 13:55:04.6565|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| And...
    2020-05-01 13:57:58.3275|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| Then I could return to the original 
    2020-05-01 13:57:58.3275|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| layout for subsequent lines! 
    2020-05-01 13:57:58.3275|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| So I could send more
    2020-05-01 13:57:58.3275|INFO|BlahBlah.Driver| useless information to the target (LOL)
```

I am sure this is basic stuff. But I am new to this logging framework and I just can't come up with, or search and find, a viable solution.

But, I am configuring NLog programatically. This is how our setup is currently done...

```
public static Logger nLogSetupGeneric(string nLogFileName)
{
    LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
    FileTarget logfile = new FileTarget() { FileName = nLogFileName, Name = "logfile" };
    config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, logfile));
    LogManager.Configuration = config;
    Logger localNlog = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    return localNlog;
}
```

Comment: You are talking about before and after. Could you update your question with what you were logging before, and what you are logging now? Together with displaying what output you got before, and what what output you are getting now? And finally give an example of how the output should be?

Comment: updated my question, hopefully more clear now.

Comment: The easy solution is just to capture the additional lines in StringBuilder, and when completed then log the contents of the StringBuilder.